# Symfony Form Collection Twig Rendering

Tags: php, jquery, forms, symfony, twig

I have a problem with my twig rendering for form collection on edit form.
The form loads with no problems but the collection field has the label doubled and modified from option to numbers the jsfiddle will show what i mean.

1. [jsfiddle output of the html](https://jsfiddle.net/5tfph1ta/)
2. [Also a screenshot](https://snag.gy/NzC78p.jpg)

**Twig Template:**

```
{% block body %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <a href="#" class="add-choice btn btn-default" aria-label="Add Choice">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                Adauga Camp
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h1>Editeaza intrebarea</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {{ form_start(edit_form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal'} } ) }}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form_label(edit_form.question, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-2 control-label'} } ) }}
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                {{ form_widget(edit_form.question, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} } ) }}
                                {{ form_errors(edit_form.question) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form_label(edit_form.surveyId, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-2 control-label'} } ) }}
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                {{ form_widget(edit_form.surveyId, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} } ) }}
                                {{ form_errors(edit_form.surveyId) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form_label(edit_form.fieldType, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-2 control-label'} } ) }}
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                {{ form_widget(edit_form.fieldType, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} } ) }}
                                {{ form_errors(edit_form.fieldType) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form_label(edit_form.categoryId, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-2 control-label'} } ) }}
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                {{ form_widget(edit_form.categoryId, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} } ) }}
                                {{ form_errors(edit_form.categoryId) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                {{ form_widget(edit_form._token, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} } ) }}
                                {{ form_errors(edit_form._token) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="multiple-choice-prototype"
                         data-prototype="{{ form_widget(edit_form.answerId.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
                        {{ form_widget(edit_form.answerId) }}
                    </div>
                    {{ form_widget(edit_form) }}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-default">Salveaza</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {{ form_end(edit_form) }}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                {{ form_start(delete_form) }}
                                <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ path('surveyquestion_index') }}">Inapoi</a>
                                <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Sterge">
                                {{ form_end(delete_form) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**Twig for the field:**

```
{% block _survey_question_answerId_entry_widget %}
    <div class="row multiple-choice-container">
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form_label(form.value, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-2 control-label'} } ) }}
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>
                    {{ form_widget(form.value, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} } ) }}
                    {{ form_errors(form.value) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a href="#" class="add-choice btn btn-default" aria-label="Add Choice">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="remove-choice btn btn-default" aria-label="Remove Choice">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    ->add('answerId', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_options' => [
          'label' => false,
        ],
        'entry_type' => AnswerType::class,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'label' => false,
        'by_reference' => false,
    ])
```

This should do the job

Answer (score 1):

remove `{{ form_label(form.value, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-2 control-label'} } ) }}`

Comment: yeap this part works but since i have my form shared with the new action if i remove the label i won't have a label set on new action and i don't really want to have my label named as 0 , 1 , 2 , 3

Comment: also removing it will not remove the numbering. did a test right now :D

Answer (score 0):

Set label to false in your form type

Example :

```
$builder->add('yourAttribute', null, array('label' => false));
```